# Qt: How to make translucent, windowless, chromeless window draggable?

Tags: c++, qt, window, qml

I have a window based on a semitransparent image:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtWebKit 1.1
  Image {
       source: "qrc:/assets/bg.png"
  }
```

And something like this in main window

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
      setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");

      /* turn off window decorations */
      setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

      ui = new QDeclarativeView;
      ui->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/assets/ui.qml"));\

      setCentralWidget(ui);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
```

and

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QDeclarativeView *ui;
};
 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I wonder how to make my window draggable across the screen (user presses on an image and drugs window around..)?

Comment: I think you'll need to create an event handler for mouse click & drag events, and change the window position from inside those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplement `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseReleaseEvent()` to know when the user is holding the mouse down, then reimplement `mouseMoveEvent()` and if the user is holding the mouse down, move the widget.

```
// **Untested code**
protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) { _mouseIsDown = true; }
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) { _mouseIsDown = false; }
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) { if(_mouseIsDown) { move(event->pos() + globalPos()); } }
```

Comment: @Wazery - That is why I marked it as "Untested code".  I am just trying to show the idea behind solving this problem.  I have used very similar code to do this exact same thing myself.  What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <Qpoint>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    ...

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    QPoint LastPoint;
    QPoint LastTopLeft;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
             QPoint Point=event->globalPos();
             LastTopLeft=this->frameGeometry().topLeft();
             LastPoint=Point;
        }
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)) {
             const QPoint Point=event->globalPos();
             QPoint offset=Point-LastPoint;
             this->move(LastTopLeft+offset);
    }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I removed the first two declarations.

Comment: Did you notice that this question was asked and accepted an answer on April of 2012?